# InsertCommand inside of code behind

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I came across the followng code in the code behind and wondering 
if this may be a good practice in terms of inserting a record 
programmatically:

```
protected void ButtonMain_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string sConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQL1"].ConnectionString;
    SqlDataSource dbQ = new SqlDataSource();
    dbQ.ConnectionString = sConn;
    dbQ.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO data1_DropDownLists (ParamID, ddlValue) VALUES ('" + ddlAllParams.SelectedValue + "','" +
        txtddl.Text + "')";
    dbQ.Insert();
    DropDownGrid.DataBind();
    dbQ = null;

}
```

What I have seen is before is something like:

```
     string query = "INSERT INTO data1_DropDownLists vALUES ...";
     cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
     conn.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

so was not sure of what the benefit may be to using the above method using InsertCommand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`SqlDataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is a control in the System.Web namespace. It can be used as datasource for web-databound controls like `Repeater` or `GridView`.

It is a control which should be used declaratively on the aspx markup and not in codebehind. It's like an interface between the GUI and the DAL. Normally you should avoid this kind of hardlinking. Instead you should separate GUI(ASPX), BLL(codebehind or class libraries etc.) and DAL (ADO.NET or Entity framework etc.).

I would suggest to use the most direct way, using an ADO.NET `SqlCommand`:

```
// use using-statement to ensure that the connection gets closed even in case of an error
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Table(Column)VALUES(@Column)", con))
    {
        // use parameters to avoid SQL-Injection
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column", value);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I am doing a databind(), in terms of best practice, should that be used within the using{} or outside of it?

Comment: Since these are two totally different things, you should separate them from each other. The first method inserts data into a database table. The second method binds data to a control. So you should first call your method which inserts that record, then you should call your method which loads the datasource and binds the DropDownList. Separation is important in terms of readability,maintainability and reusability(f.e. you don't always want to insert a record when you want to show a drodown).

Answer (score 0):

[The SqlDataSource class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.aspx) has four command properties, one for each sql action: `SelectCommand`, `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand`, `DeleteCommand`.

Once an instance is created, each of the command property can be set.

The class also exposes a two arguments constructor `SqlDataSource(String, String)` where the second argument specifies the SELECT command text.